Flask App works with Curl but not with HTTP request
Situation: This is my first full-stack project, I'm using HTML/CSS/Bootstrap with Python/Flask/SQLite for a simple rental booking webapp; home page is complete, and includes among other things a simple contact form for visitors to send questions about the rental units.
I was able to create a Flask server that upon receiving a Curl request stores a contact message in SQLite. The record includes a name, email, and contact message.
Problem: When I try to send the same from the UI I get the following error code on the Chrome Network tab: "ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE"
Notes: The Curl command is using POST, the Flask server expects POST, and the web app contact form is using POST. Flask server is running when I try this out.
Please let me know what I can read or any possible places where I can debug further.
Code snippets:

HTML Contact Form

<!-- Contact us starts -->
  <div class="contact-form">
    <div class="form-header">
      <p>Have questions? We'd love to hear from you! Please use this form to get in touch.</p>
    </div>
    <form name="contact" id="contact-form" method="POST" action="/backend/contact_messages_post_api" data-netlify="true">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="contact_name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="contact_email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
      <textarea id="contact_message" name="contact_message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="call-to-action-container centered">
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Contact us ends -->


Flask Server

import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from contact_messages_db import create_contact_table

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/frontend', static_folder='frontend')

# Call the function to create the table
create_contact_table()

@app.route('/backend/contact_messages_post_api', methods=['POST'])
def submit_contact_form():
    # Connect to the SQLite database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('contact_messages.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Handle the POST request here 
    data = request.json
    # Extract data fields
    contact_name = data.get('contact_name')
    contact_email = data.get('contact_email')
    contact_message = data.get('contact_message')
    
    # Insert data into the database
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contact_messages (contact_name, contact_email, contact_message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                   (contact_name, contact_email, contact_message))
    
    # Commit changes
    conn.commit()

    return jsonify({'message': 'Data received and stored successfully'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


Curl command

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"contact_name": "John Doe", "contact_email": "john@example.com", "contact_message": "Hello, this is test 3."}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/backend/contact_messages_post_api


Folder structure (is it a big problem if the Flask server is not enclosing the HTML files??):

root/
-- backend/
---- contact_messages_post_api.py
---- contact_messages.db
-- frontend/
---- index.html
---- styles.css
Thanks in advanced.

check logs on the server side for errors?

Added logging, but nothing was coming up either.
Later found the networking issue by pressing on the error code in the Chrome console, I saw that the header was going to http://127.0.0.1:5500/backend/contact_messages_post_api
when looking into terminal, I saw the flask server was running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Adjusted the action attribute on the form to target the actual http port: action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/backend/contact_messages_post_api"
I know it worked because I got an error log from the logging you suggested! :) Thanks much!
Now going to debug the new error :)

Added logging, but nothing was coming up either.
Later found the networking issue by pressing on the error code in the Chrome console, I saw that the header was going to 127.0.0.1:5500/backend/contact_messages_post_api when looking into terminal, I saw the flask server was running on 127.0.0.1:5000
Adjusted the action attribute on the form to target the actual http port: action="127.0.0.1:5000/backend/contact_messages_post_api"
I know it worked because I got an error log from the logging you suggested! :) Thanks much! Now going to debug the new error :)
